# Is there a way to get the jasmine report without actual execute cases?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm using [jasmine framwork](https://jasmine.github.io/) and want to get a jasmine report without actually execute cases. It should be something similiar as the 'dry run' in mocha framework.

And in the report, i want to get the spec titles and total cases number.